# adb devices not working for redmi note 3 on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

1. Enabled the developer options/USB debugging on redmi note 3 device
2. Tried **"adb devices"** command ON UBUNTU Terminal, no devices listed
3. **"lsusb"**, displays the below, No vendor name displayed

   > "Bus 002 Device 015: ID 2717:ff48"

Is there any specific drivers for Redmi note 3 device for ubuntu operating system?
Is there general driver software for all the different device vendors ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a **udev rules** file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. In the rules file, each device manufacturer is identified by a unique vendor ID, as specified by the **ATTR{idVendor}** property.

Use this format to add each vendor to the file(example vendor ID is for HTC):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

For a list of vendor IDs, see USB Vendor IDs at [android-udev-rules](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules)

Comment: Thanks, you are a life saver!!

Comment: @nithin: Thank you. Glad that it could help you!